# passing ajax varabiles

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

i have been looking around to try and work out how to pass 2 variables arcoss the page thru ajax i have at this moment a page where a check box dynamailcy saves its value to the database on the click of it but i need it to be able to only edit rows with a certian id at thi moment i have gotten this far but i am stuck. any help would be greatly appricated

```
$(function()
    {

    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
    var chkName = $(this).attr('checked');
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var checkVal = $(':checkbox[checked='+chkName+']').attr('value');
    }
    else{
    var checkVal =$("#frm input:checkbox").attr("id");  
    }
    var userid = $(':checkbox[checked='+chkName+']').attr('name');
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'request.php?uname=' + checkVal '&id'= + userid ,// this is where i cant send the &id varible across but i can send the checkVal 

            success: function(data) {

        if(data == 1){//Succues 
             alert('Data was saved in db!');
          }
        if(data == 0){//Faliure 
             alert('Data was NOT saved in db!');
          }
            }
    });
  });

  });

</script>
</head><body>
    <div class="content">
    <table border="0.02px" class="mytable">
    <thead>
    <th><strong>Paid</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Repaired</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Returned</strong></th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
            <form id="frm" name="frm">
                <td><input type="checkbox"  value="Paid"          id="Waiting on Payment"  name="29" /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"  value="Repaired"      id="Waiting on Repairs"  name="uname" /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"  value="With Student"  id="Awaiting Pickup"     name="uname" /></td>
            </form>
    </tr>
    </table>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below line in your code is incorrect:

```
url: 'request.php?uname=' + checkVal '&id'= + userid ,
```

Should be:

```
url: 'request.php?uname=' + checkVal +'&id=' + userid,
```

Also consider using `var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');` to get the checked status of checkbox.

In line `var chkName = $(this).attr('checked');`, value of *chkName*  would be '*undefined*', while the checkbox is unchecked and so as the line
`var userid = $(':checkbox[checked='+chkName+']').attr('name');`.

If I understand your code correctly, then you may try this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var isChecked = $this.prop('checked');

    var checkVal = isChecked ? $this.attr('value') : $this.attr("id");

    var userid = $this.attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",

        //url: 'request.php?uname=' + checkVal '&id' = +userid,
        url: 'request.php?uname=' + checkVal +'&id=' + userid,

        // this is where i cant send the &id varible across but i can send the checkVal
        success: function(data) {

            if (data == 1) { //Succues
                alert('Data was saved in db!');
            }
            if (data == 0) { //Faliure
                alert('Data was NOT saved in db!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: with that code it does work alot better but the reason i had an if statement was so that when i unchecked the box it would update the record in the databse to say what was in the ID field of the check box. i cant actually find anything to do that... ?

Comment: It seems, your have implemented business logic in UI, using html attributes (id, name, value) of checkBoxes. This is complicating your scenario and is not recommended. Move it at the server side; Only pass the checkBoxs' 'select' status. e.g. data: {'Paid': isPaidChecked, 'Repaired': isRepairedChecked, 'Returned': isReturnedChecked}

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is an error with the url variable you are trying to send

Current:

```
url: 'request.php?uname=' + checkVal '&id'= + userid,
```

Corrected:

```
url: 'request.php?uname=' + checkVal + '&id=' + userid,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for .serialize from jquery.
You can check the api [here](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). It has the example as well. Please go through the example how to pass serialized data.

Later in server end, you can have `$_POST['<your input name here>']` to get the value.
In addition, I see you try to get back the value from server. You can always `echo json_encode(<your data object here>)` to send to server end.

Comment: i do not see how it will work because yes it will gather the name of the checkbox which i will be using but how will i be able to get the checkVal varible which swicthes the payment status

Comment: could you please be more specific about checkVal? I really confused on how using name attribute to pass the value. What are you trying to achieve? You can always add string for checkVal after serialize like `alert($('#frm').serialize()+'&id=' + userid)` but I think you should not use name attribute to store the value except you know what are you doing. Here is the fiddle for you [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JMY4j/)